# How do I access each individual circles properties?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a traffic light for class. We are not allowed to use IDE's so This is being done in text pad. How do I access each individual circle's properties so that I can make one red, green, yellow?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lab4Panel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {


public Lab4Panel(){
}

    JRadioButton red = new JRadioButton("Red", true);
    JRadioButton yellow = new JRadioButton("Yellow");
    JRadioButton green = new JRadioButton("Green");

int height, width;
int radius = 5;
int x = -1;
int y = -1;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    if (x<0 || y<0) {
        x = getWidth() / 2 - radius;
        y = getHeight() / 2 - radius;
    }
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRect(x - 5,y - 90, 40, 120);
    g.drawOval(x,y - 80, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
    g.drawOval(x,y - 40, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
    g.drawOval(x,y, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);

}




        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getSource() == red){

                }

                else if (e.getSource() == yellow){

                }

                else if (e.getSource() == green){

                }



            }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the color in the drawing context: `g.setColor( new Color( 255,0,0 ) )`.

Comment: Won't that change each circle to the same color?

Comment: Yes, so you have to change the context color for each draw.

Comment: Ah okay I got ya, how would I fill it in though to make it look like a traffic light

Comment: The others gave you the code. (I wasn't going to give it to you as it was homework, but whatever :) )

Comment: Ya thanks I am still trying to understand what I am doing. I want to get a job in june =)

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the important modifiable object involved is the `Graphics` object `g`. Change the current color on `g` before you paint each oval:

```
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.fillOval(x,y - 80, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
g.fillOval(x,y - 40, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g.fillOval(x,y, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
```

Use [`fillOval()`<sup>javadoc</sup>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillOval%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to fill the oval instead of just drawing an outline.

Comment: So I can use fillOval for the active light and drawOval for the lights not currently active?

Comment: There's no need to do "new Color(Color.RED)", "g.setColor(Color.RED)" will suffice

Comment: @paislee there is no copy constructor on Color.  This code will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Graphics#setColor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor%28java.awt.Color%29) method to set the current color.  Then all subsequent drawing operations use that color until changed.

Also, you will want to use the [Graphics#fillOval](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillOval%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method to draw solid circles with the current color.

Your code then becomes something like:

```
g.drawRect(x - 5,y - 90, 40, 120);
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.fillOval(x,y - 80, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
g.fillOval(x,y - 40, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g.fillOval(x,y, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
```

I may have the colors out of order, but the general idea remains.

Comment: So I can use fillOval for the active light and drawOval for the lights not currently active? –

Comment: @paislee Color.RED/YELLOW/GREEN are pre-instantiated Color instances defined on the Color class.  They most certainly are objects and the code will most certainly compile.